# JavaFX MousePosition

Tags: java, javafx, mouse

I need to get x and y coordinates of a mouseclick in my application. I partially solved it in the code below by creating a point but I keep getting different coordinates depending on where I move a window of my application on the screen. I would need something constant to identify certain obejcts later. Thank you for your help!

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final Pane root = new Pane();
        setWidth(1400);
        setHeight(1000);
        Canvas background = new Canvas(getWidth(), getHeight());

        final GraphicsContext context = background.getGraphicsContext2D();
        File f = new File("background.png");
        final Image image = new Image(new FileInputStream(f));

        root.getChildren().add(background);


        root.getChildren().add(b1);
        b1.setLayoutX(1300);
        b1.setLayoutY(10);


        final Canvas animation = new Canvas(getWidth(), getHeight());
        final Canvas animation2 = new Canvas(getWidth(), getHeight());

        animation.setMouseTransparent(true);
        animation2.setMouseTransparent(true);
        final GraphicsContext context2 = animation.getGraphicsContext2D();
        final GraphicsContext context3 = animation2.getGraphicsContext2D();

        root.getChildren().add(animation);
        root.getChildren().add(animation2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, getWidth(), getHeight());

        stage.setTitle("Old Gotham");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        final Duration oneFrameAmt = Duration.millis(1000 / 60);
        final KeyFrame oneFrame;
        oneFrame = new KeyFrame(oneFrameAmt,
                new EventHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Event event) {

                        context2.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                        int offset = 700;

                        final Point p = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();

                        root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(Event event) {
                                System.out.println(p.getX());
                                System.out.println(p.getY());
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
        final Timeline tl = new Timeline(oneFrame);
        tl.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        tl.play();
    }
```

For the code presented by James_D, there is an error:

[image]

Comment: Cut your code down to the relevant sections and then clarify your question. There's a lot of irrelevant code here.

Comment: And what exactly is your problem? You already get the X and Y coordinates of the `MouseEvent`.

Comment: It is not with respect to the window of my application but to the whole screen. Assuming that I click a particular place in my application window and record (x,y), if I move my application window on the screen, clicking the same particular place again yields different (x,y). I would like it to be the same.

Comment: You have the wrong import. You need to import `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`, not the awt mouse event class. In fact, you really should not need any AWT classes at all. (The error message pretty much tells you this: "java.awt.MouseEvent cannot be converted to javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent".)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't understand why you are setting the mouse listener inside the listener for a key frame, but you need to get the coordinates from the mouse event.

[`MouseEvent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html) defines `getX()` and `getY()` to get the coordinates of the mouse event relative to the node itself, `getSceneX()` and `getSceneY()` to get the coordinates of the mouse event relative to the whole `Scene`, and (in Java 8) `getScreenX()` and `getScreenY()` to get the coordinates of the mouse event relative to the entrie screen coordinate system.

So, if you're interested in the location of the mouse relative to the window (scene), do

```
root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getSceneX());
        System.out.println(event.getSceneY());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This would provide more accurate coordinates of your mouse point..

```
root.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
{
  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event.getScreenX());
    System.out.println(event.getScreenY());
  }
});
```