# How to track a click of the mouse on the desktop

Tags: java, swing, javafx

How to track a click of the mouse on the desktop  outside of any Java components. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Google is for free ni many countries, use this ***MouseListener***, and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: With javafx that is not possible. Though with the 'awt' and 'swing' lib there is a way you can track mouse events. (Just google, you should find a lot of examples and questions simular to yours)

Comment: There is an event.getScreenX() and getScreenY in onmouseclicked handler, if i'm not mistaken. Also after like 0.5 secs of searching I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785917/javafx-mouseposition

Comment: There is no way to do this in core Java, despite what previous comments claim. What is the purpose of knowing that information?

Comment: This is my problem, and my soution https://yadi.sk/i/xfBJ-lNdxxxoa

Comment: *"..and my soution .."* I'm not following that link. If it's a solution, post it below as an answer.

Comment: if you make an almost transparent full screen layer(with mousehandler) above your application(likely in another stage for modality), then you can get screenX and screenY everywhere on screen(without the user noticing there's an almost invisible rectangle in front of him/her), and you can even dispatch events to your other layer, but clicks on anything else then your app will likely not be working as intended, i assume that is a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure Java this is maybe not possible but you can use external libraries which are based on `Java Native Interface`(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)for comunicating with your application.

You can do that using [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook).About the framework `Swing` or `JavaFX` it is your choice.

Link:

( https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook )

---

Demo:

(https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/master/src/java/org/jnativehook/example/NativeHookDemo.java )