# Click outside of pane yet inside of Scene in Javafx

Tags: javafx

This is for homework but I like to do extra than what's assigned. The goal is if we click in the pane it will show the coordinates. Got it but I don't like how I have to click inside the pane is there a way to make it where if I click in the scene it will display in the pane? (here is what I got).

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    Text text = new Text(50, 50, "Hello");
    pane.getChildren().addAll(text);
    text.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        text.setText(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() );
    });
    
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 200);
    
    primaryStage.setTitle("MouseClicker");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: Does this help? [JavaFX MousePosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785917/javafx-mouseposition)

Comment: Gonna test it out. Sounds like it should work.

Comment: *"The goal is if we click in the pane it will show the coordinates. Got it "*. You actually haven't "got it". With this code you have to click on the *text* to see the coordinates. The pane is filling the entire scene, so it's impossible to click on the scene without clicking on the pane. However, if you click on the pane, but not on the text, it won't work, so you haven't actually completed the assignment.

Comment: Good Catch James_D. I tried the scene thing and had the same results. So I think I need to reapproach the basics and see what it is that I am missing in my understanding. There is an edit listed I am going to try next. just got sick with something that had me bed ridden past couple of days so sorry for slow response.